# Selecting standard html tables by a mutral css class

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, css, vb.net

I have multiple tables with no id, a common class and a runat="server" tag. How do I dynamicly selected these tags and change a style attribute? EDIT: Jquery isn't an option, only server-side

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the elements by their common class name and then set their style attribute to something.

```
$('.<COMMONCLASSNAME>').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('style', '<NEWSTYLE>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if jQuery is an option for you: [Class Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) if you want to do this change in the code-behind: [Change Css-Class](http://forums.asp.net/p/1691125/4465641.aspx/1?Change+ItemStyle+Css+Class+in+the+Code+Behind)

Answer (score 0):

You can put all of your tables in one container like the Panel control...

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnl">
    <table >
    </table>
      ...............
      .......................
    <table>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Then iterate the panel control collection and check if the control type is HTMLTable, then add attributes to the class. e.g.

```
foreach (Control ctrl in pnl.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.GetType().Name == "HtmlTable")
        {
            ((HtmlTable)ctrl).Attributes.Add("class", "test");
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are about 50 tables so is using a class to find them possible?? tbl23 would be a bit hacky

Comment: Let me try it for you. please wait 2 min

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to add styles/class names to table elements.  Properly composed CSS can be applied to an entire table with just a class name assigned to the